# How to check if Attribute of entity is "secured" only using crm 4.0 assemblies? (field level security)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

In Dynamics 2011 installation i have an Attribute with "Secured" option enabled. And I develope a software, where I use only assemblies from crm 4.0.

With CRM 4.0 assemblies I can retrieve permissions (for particular user), but not prohibitions (i achieve this just quering following dynamic entities:  *fieldpermission, fieldsecurityprofile*). The fact, whether the field is secure i can only read from Metadata and i need crm 2011 assemblies for it (in CRM 4.0 AttributeMetadata class has no property "isSecured").

My Question is: how can i retrive, if the Attribute has field "isSecured" enabled, not using Metadata from CRM 2011, only using CRM 4.0 assemblies ? Maybe i schould query something? Or use SQL (i can use only webservices, i have no direct access to dynamics database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you not use the 2011 assemblies?

If you are forced to stick with CRM 4 assemblies, then I would do a fiddler trace of what the 2011 assemblies do and then execute a similar SOAP XML request.